# Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails - .NET - Mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, database, .net-core

I'm getting this error when trying to delete "empresas" from the database

> MySqlException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`utproject1`.`qsa`, CONSTRAINT `FK_Qsa_Empresa_EmpresaCnpj` FOREIGN KEY (`EmpresaCnpj`) REFERENCES `empresa` (`Cnpj`))

> DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

IN CONTROLLER

```
        // POST: Empresas/Delete/cnpj
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(Empresa emp)
    {
        string id = emp.Cnpj;

        id = RemovePontuacao.RmPontCnpj(id);
        var empresa = await _context.Empresa.FindAsync(id);

        if (empresa == null)
        {
            TempData["msg"] = "Este CNPJ não está cadastrado";
            return RedirectToAction("Delete");
        }
        _context.Empresa.Remove(empresa);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    private bool EmpresaExists(string id)
    {
        return _context.Empresa.Any(e => e.Cnpj == id);
    }
```

Empresa Model

```
public class Empresa
{
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "CNPJ")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha este campo.")]
    [RegularExpression("[0-9]{2}\\.?[0-9]{3}\\.?[0-9]{3}\\/?[0-9]{4}\\-?[0-9]{2}", ErrorMessage = "Digite um CNPJ válido")]
    public string Cnpj { get; set; }
    [Display(Name ="Nome")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Preencha este campo")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string DataSituacao { get; set; }
    public string MotivoSituacao { get; set; }
    public string Tipo { get; set; }
    public string Telefone { get; set; }
    public List<Qsa> Qsa { get; set; }
```

Qsa

```
public class Qsa
{
    [Key]
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Qual { get; set; }

}
```

I've tried to fix it in many ways, but I'm not getting it

DbContext

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }
    public DbSet<Empresa> Empresa { get; set; }

    //public DbSet<Qsa> Qsa { get; set; }
    //public DbSet<Atividade> Atividade { get; set; }

    //protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    //{

    //    foreach (var foreignKey in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes().SelectMany(e => e.GetForeignKeys()))
    //    {
    //        foreignKey.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.Restrict;
    //    }
    //    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    //}
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQLite EF Core - 'FOREIGN KEY constraint failed'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62626031/sqlite-ef-core-foreign-key-constraint-failed)

Answer (score 0):

you have a list Qsa in Empresa. It means Qsa has Impressa foreign key ( must be as a shadow property). I recomend you to use expicit properties

```
public class Empresa
{
    [Key]
   public int Id {get; set;}
    .....

    public virtual ICollection<Qsa> Qsas { get; set; }
}
public class Qsa
{
    [Key]
    public int Id {get; set;}
    .....

   public int EmpresaId { get; set; }
   public virtual Empresa Empresa { get; set; }

}
```

after this you can try this

```
var empresa = await _context.Empresa
                     .Include (i=> i.Qsas)
                     .Where(i=> i.Id==id)
                    .FirstOrDefault();

        if (empresa == null)
        {
            TempData["msg"] = "Este CNPJ não está cadastrado";
            return RedirectToAction("Delete");
        }
        
if( empresa.Qsas !=null)
{
_context.Qsa.RemoveRange(empresa.Qsas);
empressa.Qsas=null;
}
_context.Empresa.Remove(empresa);

await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: the application continues with the same error

Comment: @Kaike It was expected since it is not clear how Qsa and Empresa related. I am afraid You will have to change your classes. Could you post your dbcontext code pls?

Comment: i posted my dbcontext

Comment: What you have only 3 tables? And why you commented //public DbSet<Qsa> Qsa { get; set; }
    //public DbSet<Atividade> Atividade { get; set; }? And pls post Atividade  properties too.

Comment: I commented "DB Atividade" because I'm not going to use this table anymore probably. and i commented "DB Qsa" because i'm testing other things.
I need to know how to remove the List "Qsa" from the database before "Empresa", and then be able to remove "Empresa"

Comment: "the application continues with the same error " - look into DB, what constraints you have there

Answer (score 0):

In `Empresa` you have

```
public List<Qsa> Qsa { get; set; }
```

and in `Qsa` you have

```
[Key]
public string Nome { get; set; }
```

This automatically sets you to condition that you need to free your `Empresa` dependency from `Qsa` first.

Comment: I already tried to release the dependency "Empresa" from "Qsa", but I was unsuccessful